# daemon=False blocks the main process from exiting

Tags: python-multiprocessing

I was silly to think that the following will terminate the main process, leaving the child process to consequently figure out that the main process has terminated:

```
import multiprocessing
import psutil
import time


def monitor(pid):
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        print(f'monitor process {multiprocessing.current_process().pid} is monitoring pid {pid}')
        try:
            info = psutil.Process(pid).memory_full_info()
        except psutil.NoSuchProcess:
            print('monitor process detected that the monitored process has terminated')
            # some important monitor finalization operations here ...
            break

def launch_monitor():
    pid = multiprocessing.current_process().pid
    m = multiprocessing.Process(daemon=False, target=monitor, kwargs={'pid': pid})
    m.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    launch_monitor()
    print('monitor launched')
    time.sleep(1)
```

However instead, the main process never terminates, and the child process keeps monitoring it forever. Switching to daemon=True, the child process seems to (as if) terminate once the parent has.

How can I make the child process outlive the parent, and hit its `NoSuchProcess` catch block to perform some finalizations?

Is that impossible within the framework of multiprocessing itself?

---

cpython 3.10, on linux

Comment: wait, no, got mixed up with threading - processes wait for *all* their `multiprocessing`-created child processes to finish before shutting down, but they'll [try to terminate](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.12/Lib/multiprocessing/util.py#L353-L360) any daemonic children first.

Comment: Thanks, I guess it was kind of shady to gather that from the official docs (for me). Makes sense. I'll be either switching to spawning with the subprocess standard library or otherwise modify my application design to altogether avoid the idea of surviving beyond the initial process. Thanks a lot for the clarifying comment about this invariant of the multiprocessing `Process` object!